When a right derived functor preserves coproducts
Let $A$ and $B$ be Grothendieck categories, $F \colon A \to B$ is functor that preserve coproducts (if fact, I can assume that it preserves all filtered colimits). Assume that right derived functor $\mathbb R F \colon D(A) \to D(B)$ has finite cohomological dimension, which means that for any $X \in A$ complex $\mathbb R F(X)$ has only finitely many non-vanishing cohomology.
Are there a general theorems that guarantee that $\mathbb R F$ preserve coproducts?
This question arise when I was reading section 8 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7630v2 There it is proved that right derived functor $\mathbb R f_!$ on unbounded derived category has a right adjoint functor (in other words, Verdier duality holds for unbounded derived categories). Hence, as a left adjoint, functor $\mathbb R f_!$ preserves coproducts. But alternative proof of Verdier duality would be by Brown representability theorem for well-generated triangulated category (derived category of sheaves on sufficiently nice topological space). In order to apply Brown representability theorem one needs to know that functor preserves coproducts.
I don't think that in general right derived functor of a functor preserving coproducts preserves coproducts (coproduct of K-injective complexes is not K-injective). For some reasons this works in Verdier duality. For me it is interesting to understand what additional homological property functor $\mathbb R f_!$ has that guarantees preserving of coproducts.
